# Prevent apt upgrade from upgrading 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

Recently, I've discovered that running `apt update && apt upgrade` in the terminal automatically upgrades 20.04 to 20.10 - which is certainly undesirable for those of us wishing to remain on the LTS release.

I've been looking for answers to this, but have had little success, strangely.  The goal, of course, is to be able to remain on the current distribution when running `apt update && apt upgrade` in the terminal without preventing OS upgrades over the long term.  Previously, I know that the upgrade process used a different terminal command.  Is there a way to revert to that behavior?

Comment: That is definitely not the expected behaviour. Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy`?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was my own.

I am writing scripts to reproduce a particular 20.04 install configuration on a series of laptops, which requires a custom `/etc/sources.list`.  I had inadvertently copied `sources.list` from a groovy-gorilla machine to serve as a template.  Naturally, Focal Fossa wasn't going be around for very much longer. :)  I guess I would have anticipated `apt upgrade` to throw a cryptic error for having done that, so I didn't think to look there until after I posted... Whoops.

As an aside, the fact that ubuntu upgrades flawlessly by simply pointing it to a different release repo is, frankly, really cool.  Even if it makes me look like a bonehead on the internet. :)

Comment: I closed your question, since as you explained, this was a misunderstanding on your part so it's unlikely to help future users. However, thank you very much for taking the time to post an answer!